# Right type for I/O functions with argument in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I want to implement a function that asks different questions in base of sex.  However I fail in giving it the right Type.

```
askDifferentQuestion :: String -> IO String
askDifferentQuestion sex = do
  putStrLn "ciao"

main = do
  sex <- getLine
  askDifferentQuestion sex
```

If I execute I get

```
test.hs:3:3:
    Couldn't match expected type `String' with actual type `()'
    Expected type: IO String
      Actual type: IO ()
    In the return type of a call of `putStrLn'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: putStrLn "ciao"
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Why am I doing it wrong?

Comment: One thing you could do in this situation is omit the type declaration for `askDifferentQuestion` and then use the `:t` command to ask ghci what was the type that it inferred automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type `IO String` means an input/output action that yields a `String` when run. As is, `askDifferentQuestion` results in `()`, which usually indicates an insignificant value. This is because the only action to be run is `putStrLn` whose type is `IO ()`, *i.e.*, you run it for its side-effect only.

Assuming your type is correct, change the definition of `askDifferentQuestion` to both prompt the user *and* `return` the response. For example

```
askDifferentQuestion :: String -> IO String
askDifferentQuestion sex = putStrLn (q sex) >> getLine
  where q "M" = "What is the airspeed velocity of an unladen swallow?"
        q "F" = "How do you like me now?"
        q "N/A" = "Fuzzy Wuzzy wasn’t fuzzy, was he?"
        q "N" = "Why do fools fall in love?"
        q "Y" = "Dude, where’s my car?"
        q _ = "Why do you park on a driveway and drive on a parkway?"
```

Answer (score 4):

The type of `putStrLn` is `String -> IO ()` not `String -> IO String`.

Comment: ... therefore the type for `askDifferentQuestion` is `askDifferentQuestion :: String -> IO ()`.